# Невозможно вызвать функцию с данным списком аргументов

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

У меня в форме есть элемент textbox1. Также, у меня есть вот такой вектор, в который с помощью метода push_back я кладу строку:

```
std::vector<string> vec;
    vec.push_back("ыфвывфвфы");//с этим проблем нет
```

Но при попытке присвоить свойству text элемента textbox1 значение 0 ячейки вектора появляется ошибка: E1767 невозможно вызвать функцию "System::Windows::Forms::TextBox::Text::set" с данным списком аргументов.

Присвоить я пытаюсь вот так:

```
textBox1->Text = vec[0];
```

Comment: Я не спец в cli, но там случайно не строка в стиле С - `char*` - нужна? Вот так - `textBox1->Text = vec[0].c_str();` не работает?

Comment: К сожалению нет, та же самая ошибка

Comment: Ну, я и не утверждал, что это так, просто первое, что на ум пришло - как я сказал, cli не знаю. Посмотрите, как описан сеттер, что он должен принимать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winforms все контролы используют типы .NET, соответственно на стороне С++ следует использовать `::std::wstring`, а не `::std::string`, а потом каждый раз преобразовывать в `System.String`.

```
::std::vector<::std::wstring> vec{};
vec.emplace_back(L"ыфвывфвфы");
textBox1->Text = gcnew System::String(vec[0].c_str());
```